# Changing referencing style depending on context

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

One style of referencing substatements of theorems/lemmas/corollaries/etc. is the following. Suppose we have the following text (my translation of the first part of [SGA 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203.pdf)).

> **CHAPTER I: ÉTALE MORPHISMS**
>
> ...
>
> **2. Quasi-finite morphisms**
>
> **Proposition 2.1.** Let ... Then equivalent conditions are:
>
> (i) ...
>
> (ii) ...
>
> (iii) ...

I would like to reference the items in the enumerated list as

- `(i)`, `(ii)`, `(iii)` in the proof of this proposition (in SGA, this particular example might be a bad one as there is no proof to this proposition and as this referencing style is even used in the *Corollary 2.2* immediately following this propsition);
- `(2.1, (i))`, `(2.1, (ii))`, `(2.1 (iii))` in all other places of this *CHAPTER I*;
- `(I, 2.1, (i))`, `(I, 2.1, (ii))`, `(I, 2.1, (iii))` in all other places outside of *CHAPTER I*.

This style is (more or less) followed in SGA and EGA (with commas in EGA, without commas in SGA). I'm aware that one could do this manually by `label`ing the chapter, the proposition and the items in the list, and then providing three different commands to realise these styles. But I'm searching for a context-aware mechanism, i.e. I'd only `label` the three items in the list, and the single referencing command would yield the correct style depending on where it is called. Such a mechanism would need to save the associated proposition and chapter for each item, and then compare these to get the right style. I also know of `\p@enumi` for prefixing `\theenumi`, but don't know how to make it work. Any ideas or packages are welcomed.

---

**Edit:** I don't know if this is of much help, but here a poor man's solution to the problem (an MWE as requested in the comments):

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{section}{chapter}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textup{(\roman*)}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itmref}{ m o o }{% itm, thm, ch
    \IfValueT{#2}{(}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{\ref{#3}, }%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\ref{#2}, }%
    \ref{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{)}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thmref}{ m o }{% thm, ch
    (\IfValueT{#2}{\ref{#2}, }%
    \ref{#1})%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{} \label{ch}
\section{}
\begin{theorem} \label{thm1}
    Let \dots
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{itm}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
    \itmref{itm}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm2}
\end{theorem}

\itmref{itm}[thm1],
\thmref{thm2}

\chapter{}

\itmref{itm}[thm1][ch],
\thmref{thm2}[ch]

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 3:

[image]

The goal would be to have one command `\itmref` which does not need the optional arguments `[thm]` or `[thm][ch]` and still yields the correct result in all cases. Similar for `\thmref`. Even better if there is some command `\magicref` which combines both `\itmref` and `\nameref` functionalities.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE?

Comment: @cfr I added a (somewhat) MWE.